# Does JQuery/Django have a way to build "click the text to edit"?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

A Flickr page displays the title and description of the photo.

When I click on the description, it will turn it into a text-box, with a Save button.  Then, I can edit what I want...and click "Save."

It'll save it via AJAX.  It doesn't go to a different page or anything...it just turns the current description into a wiki-like text box.

Comment: write your own code :) Show text in div. On clicking div show text box. use show() hide() functions.on submit or click call ajax and save and show the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jEditable

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html for demo

Comment: also: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html and
download: http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.time.js